# change hour format for a plot in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, datetime

I been searcing for hours now. In Python I used for loop to create subplots, so I have not defined ax and fig. So i don't seem to find any solution no involving them.

```
df_june['hours']=df_june['date'].dt.hour
*df_june is dataset only for 1st of june*

for i in important_cols[1:]:
    sns.lineplot(x='hours', y=i, data=df_june)
    plt.xticks([0,4,8,12,16,20,24])
    plt.show()

*import_cols are columns I am only needing to plot*
```

I used plt.xticks([0,4,8,12,16,20,24]) for creating ticks , but I would love it to be for everyhour and in format 00:00 and 24:00 instead.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use list comprehension to create `xticklabels` from `get_xticks()`, adding `':00'` to the end of the `xtick`, prepending `'0'`, then shortening the `str` to (the last) 5 indexes (i.e. formatted `xx:xx`):

```
subplot_number = 0
for i in important_cols[1:]:
    subplot_number += 1
    ax = plt.subplot(1, len(important_cols[1:]), subplot_number)
    sns.lineplot(x='hours', y=i, data=df_june)
    ax.set_xticks([0,4,8,12,16,20,24])
    ax.set_xticklabels([_xticklabel[-5:] for _xticklabel in ['0' + str(_xtick) + ':00' for _xtick in ax.get_xticks()]])
    plt.show()
```

`xticklabels` look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I did was change to this

```
df['time']=df['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

AND

```
for i in important_cols[1:]:
    sns.lineplot(x='time', y=i, data=df_june)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.show()
```

[image]